# Read a Specific Line of a File with Groovy

Tags: groovy

Can some one help me to read a file line by line,

I have this code - but this code will print all the content. I need to display only the 5th(or specific) line by line, hence I want to access and print any line dynamically. I need to print 5th line of the text file.

```
//read from file

myFile = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\ABCEDFG\\Desktop\\soapUI\\params.txt")
printFileLine = { log.info "File line: " + it }
myFile.eachLine(0, printFileLine)
```

Please help -Appreciate your help in advance!

^Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's sloppy and wasteful, but you can do

```
log.info "Line 5: " +  myFile.readLines().get(4)
```

Comment: Thank you Art Taylor. This is working good. Appreciate your help!
Also tell me, How can i get total count of number of lines in the file?

Comment: `readLines()` returns you a `java.util.List<String>` object which contains all of the lines. `List` has a method `size()` which tells you how many items the list contains. So basically: `myFile.readLines().size()`.

Comment: Also, if you are using this solution, you better save that list somewhere and reuse it to avoid useless IO operations. For example: `List<String> fileLines = myFile.readLines(); String line4 = fileLines.get(4); String line5 = fileLines.get(5); int count = fileLines.size();`

Comment: Thank Max. Even though i find it my myself. Keep in touch!

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want it all in memory, you can do:

```
String readLine( File f, int n ) {
  String line = null
  f.withReader { r ->
    while( n-- > 0 && ( ( line = r.readLine() ) != null ) ) ;
  }
  line
}
```

Then, to print the 5th line:

```
File infile = new File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\ABCEDFG\\Desktop\\soapUI\\params.txt")
String line = readLine( infile, 5 )
println line
```

However, if you want to read many lines in a random order access way, this might be wasteful as you will spool down the file from the start every time.  However, if you can't load it into memory as it's too big, there's not much else you can do

Comment: Thank you Tim. This is also working fine. 
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Works fine, but there is a  `+1` shift, i.e. to get first line  `readLine( file, 1 )` is used instead of `get(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in any optimized way. You have 2 options here:

1. Load all file into memory and build a line index.
2. Each time you need to access line N, read all lines from 0 to (N-1).

Explanation:

Line break is simply a character. Without reading ALL characters you can't tell the filesystem to magically skip the file to line N. You need to actually find the N'th line-break character to know where the N'th line starts.